# How to save selected item in an activeX dropdown in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dropdown, when I select an item and save, it saves but when I select and item and go to another sheet then comeback, the selection is lost. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's something about how you are making the dropdown? In the animated gif below I show how to make one, and demonstrate that the selection is not lost when going to another sheet. Notice that the `link cell (B2)` is also working as expected, retaining the index of the selection after changing sheets.

[image]

Comment: mine is an activeX dropdown not just a dropdown

Comment: The implied solution here is to use a `LinkedCell` to store the  ComboBox's value. If this solution doesn't work for you VBA might be used to reset the ComboBox to the value that it had before. The question is whether you would need to keep that value even after closing the document.

Comment: I am able to keep the value on save. I just don't want to lose it when selecting a different sheet

Comment: @Variatus Exactly Right: use the Link Cell to solve this problem.

Comment: You might link a cell hidden behind the control or make the linked cell's content invisible. It's just for the ActiveX to remember what was selected.

Comment: @TonyM How did you embed an inline video. :)

Comment: 1) Screen recordings using QuickTime is easy on Macs, and then 2) http://ezgif.com/maker -- If you have Windows, QuickTime won't work, but you could use PowerPoint 2013 or later

Comment: Thanks Tony! Now I remember how to do this as I tried something similar in the past but just forgot about that. :)